# Need typename error (template related error)

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class called node inside another class which is templated. Some of the methods of class Node returns Node pointer. This is an excerpt of how I implemented

```
 template <typename T>
 class myClass{
 ....
     class Node{
         Node* getNodePointer();
         ...
     }
 }     
 ... 
 template <typename T>
 myClass<T>::Node* myClass<T>::Node::getNext()  
 { return next;  }
```

When I compile above code, I get this error " myClass.h:138:1: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘myClass::Node’ because ‘myClass’ is a dependent scope". How do I fix this problem? Many thanks

Comment: `typename myClass<T>::Node* myClass<T>::Node::getNext()`.  Note the `typename` at the beginning of that.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords?rq=1) deals with the **why**.

Comment: @GuyGreer THX for the low hanging fruits ;) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I fix this problem?

The compiler's error message s pretty clear about this point:
To use nested `class`es, `struct`s or `typedef`initions from a template class you need to add the `typename` keyword to tell the compiler you want to use it as a type:

```
   template <typename T>
   typename myClass<T>::Node* myClass<T>::Node::getNext()  { // ...
// ^^^^^^^^ << Add typename keyword
```

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, the compiler has no idea that `myClass<T>::Node` is now or ever will be a type. Think of it this way:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;
};

template <typename T>
class B
{
public:
   typename A<T>::value_type x;
};

template <> A<int> { public: static int value_type=10;}
```

You have to make the promise to the compiler that the type is a typename. It defaults to assuming that it is a value.